# Using the Distribution rule to go from $(\sim A\vee\sim(B\,\&\,C))\,\&\,(\sim A\vee C)$ to $\sim A\vee(\sim(B\,\&\,C)\,\&\,C)$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am working through an elementary logic textbook to pass a logic qualifying exam I have to take (I'm a philosophy grad student). Can someone show me why the inference below is a valid instance of the Distribution rule?

In the textbook I'm using, the Distribution rule is defined in terms of the following equivalences:

$$(p\land(q\lor r)) \iff ((p\land q)\lor(p\land r)) \tag 1$$

$$(p\vee(q\wedge r)) \iff ((p\vee q)\wedge (p\vee r)) \tag2$$

What I'm trying to figure out is why (as the textbook problem states) the following inference is a valid instance of this rule.

The inference moves from this symbolic formula:

$$(\neg A\vee\neg(B\wedge C))\wedge (\neg A\vee C)$$

To this one:

$$\lnot A\lor(\lnot(B\land C)\land C)$$

The textbook states that this is a valid use of the Distribution rule. But I couldn't figure out how. Could someone explain this to me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It follows immediately from the second given rule:

$$\big(\color{red}{\neg A} \lor \color{blue}{\neg (B\land C)}\big) \land (\color{red}{\neg A} \lor \color{green}C) \equiv \color{red}{\neg A} \lor \big(\color{blue}{\neg (B\land C)} \land \color{green}C\big)$$

Perhaps to make it easier to see, let $p=\neg A$, $q=\neg (B\land C)$, and $r=C$ :

$$(\color{red}p \lor \color{blue}q) \land (\color{red}p \lor \color{green}r) \equiv \color{red}p \lor (\color{blue}q \land \color{green}r)$$

Comment: Thanks so much.